# Nexus 5 on android 6.0.1 not detected by my computer

Tags: android

Since I installed the last update, my computer doesn't recognise my Nexus 5.
When I plug it to the computer my phone is charging and nothing happens.
Here is what I tried.
I enabled the developer option, I set the file transfer option to MTP and I activated the USB debug option. It didn't work.
I tried to reboot my phone and my computer.
I tried some tricks like unplugging the phone from the computer, activating the debug option, locking the phone, plugging it to the computer, unlocking the phone but it still didn't work.
I also tried different cables without success.
I couldn't find the solution on any topics.
(My computer runs ubuntu 14.04)

Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Did you try with USB adb installer ?

Comment: I have adb installed. I tried the command 'adb devices' which should list all the devices but it listed nothing. Is that what you meant Saveen ?

Comment: I upgraded adb to the latest version. Still not working

Comment: Sorry, I didn't pick up on the fact, that it was working perfectly fine before. Disregard my previous comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem comes from the hardware. The plug on my phone is broken. It can charges but it doesn't detect that it is plug on my computer. Even on a windows or mac machine.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with ubuntu 14.04 and my HTC. Just tap on the text  "Connected as a media device" in status bar and wait while smartphone determined. It works for me.

Comment: The problem is I've got nothing in the status bar. In fact nothing is displayed on my phone except the battery which is recharging.

Comment: @Mtoypc you can change MTP on PTP mode in settings? Happens something?

Comment: Yes I can do that. But nothing happens :/

Comment: Also I don't understand why but when I try to change the config for USB transfert (e.g MTP to PTP), even if I click on PTP it automatically put charged only. I have to click several times on the same option to actually  select another configuration.